# Reactjs TypeError: Unable to get property 'string' of undefined or null reference Anonymous function

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, typeerror, react-proptypes

Reactjs
TypeError:

> Unable to get property 'string' of undefined or null reference
>   Anonymous function

```
Error-->Field.propTypes = {
  27 | 
  28 |   label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  29 |   onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
```

Comment: please put the code you are using.

Comment: Without code it is not possible to answer

Comment: Please share the code where it is throwing error

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `PropTypes` is not recognized. Make sure you've imported it like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // <== this line

// Field class definition
//...

Field.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    //... 
}
```